Understanding uniformized time in the Kepler problem with two fixed centres
I'm trying to understand in details the problem of a single electron of mass $m$ "orbiting" around two fixed centres (with different charges).
Some references include


Strand, Michael P., and William P. Reinhardt. "Semiclassical quantization of the low lying electronic states of H2+." The Journal of Chemical Physics 70.8 (1979): 3812-3827.
Erikson, Henry A., and E. L. Hill. "A note on the one-electron states of diatomic molecules." Physical Review 75.1 (1949): 29.
Ewgenii, Malkov, et al. "Investigations of the two fixed centers problem and Henon-Heiles potential potential based on Poincaré section" Известия НАН РК. Серия физико-математическая 1 (2019): 55-61.
Kobayashi, M., & Yamada, K. (2019). Spacecraft orbit around two fixed bodies. Acta Astronautica, 160, 615-624.
Deprit, A. "Le probleme a deux centres fixes", Bull. Soc. Math. Belg. 14, 12 (1962).


The results of Kobayashi are cool, including 8-shaped orbits.  Variants of this material are also discussed in some textbooks, such as Problem 8.12 of

Johnson, Porter W. Classical Mechanics with applications. World Scientific, 2010.

Taking the centres to be on the $\hat x$ axis at $\pm R$ from the original, and using:
$$
\tilde t= t\sqrt{\frac{e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 mR^3}}\qquad \text{(dimensionless time)} \\
X=\frac{x}{R}\, \quad Y=\frac{y}{R} \qquad \text{(dimensionless coordinates)} 
$$
one obtains without too much effort, using elliptic coordinates where
$$
X=\cosh(\xi)\cos(\eta)\,  \quad Y=\sinh(\xi)\sin(\eta)\, ,
$$
the (dimensionless) Hamiltonian
$$
\tilde H=\frac{1}{\cosh^2\xi-\cos^2\eta}\left(\frac12 p^2_\xi+\frac12 p^2_\eta-(Z_1+Z_2)\cosh(\xi)-(Z_1-Z_2)\cos(\eta)\right)\, . \tag{1}
$$
Now, in their numerical approach Strand (and other authors) follow Deprit and introduce "uniformized time $\tau$ " defined by
$$
d\tilde t=(\cosh^2\xi-\cos^2\eta)d\tau \tag{2}
$$
so $\tilde{H} d\tilde t= \hat{H} d\tau$.  This essentially removes the denominator prefactor from Eq. (1) to produce
$$
\hat H=\frac12 p^2_\xi+\frac12 p^2_\eta-(Z_1+Z_2)\cosh(\xi)-(Z_1-Z_2)\cos(\eta)\,  .\tag{3}
$$
I can't understand Eq. (2) or its justification.  It just seems arbitrary, and Deprit introduces this without much justification that I can see.   Deprit claims that
$K$ (the Kamiltonian?) given by
$$
K=(H-h)(\cosh^2\xi-\cos^2\eta)=0
$$
where $h$ is the energy of the system, can function as the new Hamiltonian.

Clearly, neither $\xi$ nor $\eta$ in general are independent of time (or dimensionless time) so I fail to how $\hat H$ is equivalent (in any sense) to $\tilde H$.
What is the physical meaning of the uniformized time as defined in Eq. (1) and how can one get insight into its more geneal use to remove common prefactors in a Hamiltonian?

I find it easier to think in terms of the Hamiltonian Jacobi equation (HJE). Your equation (1) becomes:
$$
\frac{1}{\cosh^2\xi-\cos^2\eta}\left(\frac12 \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \xi}\right)^2+\frac12\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \eta}\right)^2-(Z_1+Z_2)\cosh(\xi)-(Z_1-Z_2)\cos(\eta)\right)=h
$$
Recall that the stationary HJE is obtained by separating time:
$$
\mathcal S= S-ht
$$
Therefore, multiplying by $\xi^2-\eta^2$ amounts to rescaling time. This holds as well for the EoM's as the two approaches are equivalent. Yes, the two Hamilotians $\tilde H$ and $K$ do not describe the same system, but $K=0$ solutions with the time rescaled do correspond to $\tilde H = h$ solutions and vice versa. You can check this out explicitly from the EoM's. If you are interested in the actual trajectories (the trace of the solutions), then the rescaling of time is irrelevant.
The reason why you multiply by $\xi^2-\eta^2$ is to separate the action. You can now solve it using the ansatz:
$$
S=S_\xi(\xi)+S_\eta(\eta)
$$
satisfying:
$$
\frac12\left(\frac{dS}{d\xi}\right)^2-(Z_1+Z_2)\cosh(\xi)-h\cosh^2\xi=C \\
\frac12\left(\frac{dS}{d\eta}\right)^2-(Z_1-Z_2)\cos(\eta)+h\cos^2\eta=-C
$$
with $h,C$ constant of motion which allow you to integrate the system. $C$ is to elliptic coordinates as angular momentum is to polar coordinates.
I wrote another answer with more references on a similar topic Reaching a closed form solution for S in the Hamilton-Jacobi equation.

right. I agree with what you have. So your strategy is to NOT go to the equations of motion and push through with HJ and in some sense you are not redefining
$t$, just thinking of the uniform time $t(\xi^2-\eta^2)$ as a kind of placeholder? You can see from the screenshot of Deprit they do actually take the derivative with respect to the "uniformized time", and that's the part that puzzles me.  (I totally agree it's separable; just trying to see if I can get elliptical orbits with $Z_1\ne Z_2$ and reproduce some orbits numerically.

… in others words, I’m looking for the EoMs which differ (in some essential way?) depending if I use $\tilde H$ or $\hat H$.

I edited your answer as I found a typo in my original expression.
